# What may be formatted as code?

Tags: support, code-formatting, feedback

The answer might be clear, but to me it's not.

Recently I exaggerated a bit with the code formatting using the ` sign. While other see rivers, when used to often, I like it for it suppresses scrollbars on over length oneliners which I consider to be unpleasant. But my main point is: **Words which tend to step out of the text semantically I tend to format as code.**

For instance in

> I have .ui, .py and .pyc files generated. Now, when I edit the .py file, how will it [...]

I'd highlight those `.**` endings, cause this way while reading it indicates something like: now-comes-an-identifier. Do you know what I mean? Note that concerning this example I'd treat PDF or HDF differently, because the capitals already fulfill that function.

I'd like to have a quick feedback on whether I strictly should stick to use "`" for code only or whether there is a "gray area".

Answer (score 10):

Use backticks for things that are intended for a computer.
Do not use backticks for things that are intended for a human.

Example: `.ui`, `.pdf`, etc. are parts of file names, intended to be typed and displayed on a computer. Use backticks.
Counter-example: “a PDF file” is text intended for a human. PDF is an acronym, spelled in all caps. Do not use backticks for this.

Example:

> A PDF file (that is, a file in PDF format) usually has the `.pdf` extension. You can view it with programs such as Acrobat Reader, which you can invoke from the “Acrobat Reader” menu entry or on the command line by typing `acroread`.

Code blocks can be used for code. They should not be used for text, but can be used when visual formatting is required, for example to typeset tables or ASCII art diagrams.